# Erro BABEL_PARSE_ERROR utilizando array no ES6

Tags: javascript, bundle, ecmascript-6

Olá!
Sou novo utilizando ES6, fiz a instalação do Babel, portanto ao utilizar array o Bundle acusa BABEL_PARSE_ERROR. Aparece assim:
SyntaxError: C:\xampp\htdocs\ES6\main.js: Unexpected token (3:20)

O código que estou utilizando é o seguinte:

```
class todoList{
    constructor(){
        this.todos[];
    }

    addTodo(){
        this.todos.push("Novo todo");
        console.log(this.todos);
    }

}

const MinhaLista = new todoList();    

document.getElementById('novotodo').onclick = function(){
    MinhaLista.addTodo();
}
```

O erro está justamente no array que fica dentro do constructor:
constructor(){
        this.todos[];
    }

Alguém sabe me dizer se há alguma atualização que tenha modificado isso, ou se estou fazendo algo errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toda a atribuição de valores às variáveis no Javascript é feita utilizando um sinal de igualdade. Sejam elas strings, inteiros... ou arrays.

No código em questão faltou apenas o sinal mesmo.

```
constructor() {
   this.todos = [];
}
```

Comment: Realmente, estava faltando o sinal de igual entre todos e []. Obrigado! Falta de atenção minha xD